# How to hide html5 form validation on reseting form

Tags: html, validation, forms

I have an HTML page with input fields and two buttons: `Submit` and `Reset`. When the user clicks on `Submit`, the required validation messages come up, that's fine, but they also come up when clicking `Reset`.

HTML:

```
<html>

<body>
    <form action="insertVoucherCategory" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Voucher Category</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input  name="voucherCategory" id="voucherCategory" title="Please Enter Voucher Category" required="required" placeholder="Enter Voucher Category" tabindex="1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input  name="description" id="description" title="Please Enter Description" required="required" placeholder="Enter Description" tabindex="2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" id="btnAdd" value="Submit" tabindex="3"/></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="reset" id="btnReset" value="Reset" tabindex="4"/></td>
            </tr>
        <table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is what happens on `Reset`:**
[image: Actual response]

**This is what I want:**
[image: Ideal response]

Comment: This is weird. Maybe it has to do with the id or the reset which is the same as the submit

Comment: I don't think there is a way to remove pseudoclass :invalid from the inputs.

Comment: add it Jsfiddle  My dear Friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="hideMsg()" />

function hideMsg(){
  $('.errMsg').hide();
  $('.required').val('');
  $('.required').addClass('blueBorder');
  $('.required').removeClass('redBorder');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `type="reset"` attribute on an `<input>` or `<button>` to automatically use HTML5 validation to clear the validation highlighting.

Tested satisfactorily on IE11 and Edge on Windows 10...